# Springboot fails to run creating RestTemplate (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.markers.KMappedMarker)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

After upgrading my project to **spring-boot-starter-parent 3.2.1**, I got the following error while trying to start my SpringBoot application

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Factory method 'restTemplate' threw exception with message: kotlin/jvm/internal/markers/KMappedMarker
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:177) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/markers/KMappedMarker
```

I instantiate `RestTemplate` using the `RestTemplateBuilder` as follows

```java
@Configuration
public class BeansFactory {
  @Bean
  public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.build();
  }
}
```

If I don't use the builder and I just create the object with the constructor `new RestTemplate()`, then it works, but it sounds dirty and it has been working well so far before the upgrade.

I am using Java 17.

My `pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.acme.cool</groupId>
    <artifactId>cool-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <name>cool-app</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <!-- Dependencies -->
        <okta-jwt.version>0.5.7</okta-jwt.version>
        <springdoc.version>2.3.0</springdoc.version>
        <semver4j.version>5.2.2</semver4j.version>
        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <mockito-inline.version>5.2.0</mockito-inline.version>
        <mockito-junit.version>5.6.0</mockito-junit.version>
        <!-- Plugins -->
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.12.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.2.3</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.8.11</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
        <formatter-maven-plugin.version>2.23.0</formatter-maven-plugin.version>
        <impsort-maven-plugin.version>1.9.0</impsort-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Okta -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.jwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-jwt-verifier</artifactId>
            <version>${okta-jwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.jwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-jwt-verifier-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${okta-jwt.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mockito -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito-inline.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito-junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--Semantic version-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.semver4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>semver4j</artifactId>
            <version>${semver4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>repackage</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>cool-app</finalName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-info</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.revelc.code.formatter</groupId>
                <artifactId>formatter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${formatter-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configFile>${project.basedir}/eclipse-hmp-style.xml</configFile>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>format</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.revelc.code</groupId>
                <artifactId>impsort-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${impsort-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <removeUnused>true</removeUnused>
                    <staticGroups>*</staticGroups>
                    <groups>java.,javax.,org.,com.</groups>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sort</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: why is it looking for a Kotlin dependency ?

Comment: yes, indeed. Good question... No idea

Comment: it might be intellij related
Could you try to run a project from within a shell ? 
`mvn spring-boot:run` and see if it the error still happens
If it doesn't I suggest you to clean up the Intellij maven caches
Also, keep in mind that starting from Spring boot 3 RestTemplate is deprecated and it's recommended to use WebClient instead
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-webclient.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be Intellij-related

To verify try to run the project from the shell `mvn spring-boot:run` if it works then the problem is with Intellij

One of the Jetty maintainers encountered the same problem with OkHttp
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-24991/JPS-Maven-cannot-access-kotlin.jvm.internal.markers.KMappedMarker-when-building-project-in-IDE
The solution is not resolved yet but the workaround would be to add the dependency

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

This workaround is ugly as your project doesn't even use Kotlin in the first place.

So I would suggest you to downgrade Intellij to something earlier than
IDEA: 2022.3.2 Build #IU-223.8617.56

Comment: your solution is fine. I confirm it works but it's not IntelliJ related, since it happens also while running the application with a maven command without passing through the IDE

Comment: that's weird, could you check that maven uses your own JDK instead of the one shipped with intellij ? mvn --version

Comment: I had the same issues while running it in my Docker image, so it's definitely not Intellij related